# Spacing in WP Blog Template?

Tags: html

How do I get bulleted/numbered lists to have a space in between them as the default on a WP blog?  So it doesn't show up as a big block like the image (and I don't have to go in manually and insert `<br>` in between them).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply a [margin](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp) on the list items:

```
li{
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```